# How to Save an image from Custom Paint?

Tags: flutter

I'm trying to make a simple app, that draw based on input of the user. Making the base functionality, i run into the problem, i'm not able to save the image. I searched and i found that i should use PictureRecorder(), but i couldn't make it work ( my fault not a bug). So i would like to ask you how should i implement the PictureRecorder and save the image to the disk using Custom Paint.

Here's the code:

```
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'dart:ui' as ui;

class Painter extends StatefulWidget {
  static String id = 'Painter';
  @override
  _PainterState createState() => _PainterState();
}

class _PainterState extends State<Painter> {
  final recorder = new ui.PictureRecorder();
  double canvasWidth = 1200;
  double canvasHeight = 1000;
  double SecondWidth = 0;
  double SecondHeight = 0;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.blueGrey,
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Center(
          child: Text(
            '⚡  ⚡',
            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.blue),
          ),
        ),
        backgroundColor: Colors.black26,
      ),
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Container(
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
          child: ListView(
            children: <Widget>[
              Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Text('⚡  ⚡'),
                      SizedBox(
                        width: 150.0,
                        child: TextField(
                          decoration: InputDecoration(
                              border: InputBorder.none, hintText: 'title'),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                  Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Text('Canvas  Height'),
                      SizedBox(
                        width: 150.0,
                        child: TextField(
                          onChanged: (value) {
                            setState(() {
                              canvasHeight = double.parse(value);
                            });
                          },
                          decoration: InputDecoration(
                              border: InputBorder.none,
                              hintText: 'Canvas. Height'),
                          inputFormatters: [
                            WhitelistingTextInputFormatter.digitsOnly
                          ],
                          keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                  Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Text('Canvas. Width'),
                      SizedBox(
                        width: 150.0,
                        child: TextField(
                          onChanged: (value) {
                            setState(() {
                              canvasWidth = double.parse(value);
                            });
                            print(canvasWidth);
                          },
                          decoration: InputDecoration(
                              border: InputBorder.none,
                              hintText: 'Canvas. Width'),
                          inputFormatters: [
                            WhitelistingTextInputFormatter.digitsOnly
                          ],
                          keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                  Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Text('Second. height'),
                      SizedBox(
                        width: 150.0,
                        child: TextField(
                          decoration: InputDecoration(
                              border: InputBorder.none,
                              hintText: 'Second. height'),
                          inputFormatters: [
                            WhitelistingTextInputFormatter.digitsOnly
                          ],
                          keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                          onChanged: (value) {
                            setState(() {
                              SecondHeight = double.parse(value);
                            });
                          },
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                  Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Text('Secon. width'),
                      SizedBox(
                        width: 150.0,
                        child: TextField(
                          decoration: InputDecoration(
                              border: InputBorder.none,
                              hintText: 'Second. Width'),
                          inputFormatters: [
                            WhitelistingTextInputFormatter.digitsOnly
                          ],
                          keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                          onChanged: (value) {
                            setState(() {
                              SecondWidth = double.parse(value);
                            });
                          },
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ],
              ),
              RaisedButton(
                onPressed: () async {
                  final picture = recorder.endRecording();
                  final img = picture.toImage(200, 200);
                  final pngBytes = await img.toByteData(format: new ui.EncodingFormat.png());
                },
                child: Text('Save Image'),
              ),
              FittedBox(
                child: SizedBox(
                  width: canvasWidth,
                  height: canvasHeight,
                  child: Container(
                    color: Colors.yellow,
                    child: CustomPaint(
                      painter: BoxInABox(
                        canvasrecorder: recorder,
                        width: canvasWidth,
                        height: canvasHeight,
                        iHeight: SecondHeight,
                        iWidth: SecondWidth,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class BoxInABox extends CustomPainter {
  @override
  BoxInABox({this.width, this.height, this.iWidth, this.iHeight, this.canvasrecorder});

  final double width;
  final double height;
  final double iWidth;
  final double iHeight;
  final canvasrecorder;

  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    final paint = Paint()
      ..style = PaintingStyle.stroke
      ..strokeWidth = 4.0
      ..color = Colors.indigo;

    canvas.drawRect(
        Rect.fromCenter(
          height: height,
          width: width,
          center: Offset(
            width / 2,
            height / 2,
          ),
        ),
        Paint()..color = Colors.green);

    canvas.drawRect(
        Rect.fromCenter(
          height: iHeight,
          width: iWidth,
          center: Offset(
            width / 2,
            height / 2,
          ),
        ),
        Paint()..color = Colors.red);
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(BoxInABox oldDelegate) => true;
}
```

Thanks in advance

Edit: updated the code, including my failed attempt to implement the recorder, P.s it gives me an error on 'error:

> The method 'toByteData' isn't defined for the class 'Future'.
>   (undefined_method at [flutterappquesion] lib\main.dart:152)' and
>   error: Undefined class 'ui.EncodingFormat'. (undefined_class at
>   [flutterappquesion] lib\main.dart:152)

Comment: post your `PictureRecorder` code

Comment: edited the main post

Comment: `final img = await picture.toImage(200, 200);`

Comment: i went back a bit to far, it should be ``` final img = picture.toImage(
                      canvasWidth.toInt(), canvasHeight.toInt()); ```

what is the error?

Answer (score 2):

Just use a `PictureRecorder` on your `Canvas`.

```
PictureRecorder pictureRecorder = PictureRecorder();
Canvas canvas = Canvas(pictureRecorder);

// Paint your canvas as you want

Picture picture = pictureRecorder.endRecording();
Image image = await picture.toImage(yourWidth, yourHeight);
```

Comment: basically i have to stop using custom paint for this right?

Comment: Yes, actually you don't need it at all for this matter.

Comment: In the future can i put either text or images into the picture using Canvas? Sorry but when i google now most of the result port me to Custom Paint

Comment: Yes, `Canvas` has a `drawImage()` method on it.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you save specific widget as an image by RepaintBoundary widget: [screenshot](https://medium.com/@agungsurya/take-a-screenshot-of-a-certain-widget-in-flutter-ad263edc4e55)

Comment: i tried this solution, it gives me Unhandled Exception: type 'RenderConstrainedBox' is not a subtype of type 'RenderRepaintBoundary , I'm about to open a thread about this, since RepaintBoundary seems the best option for my case

Comment: Here's the post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61458764/flutter-the-widget-repaintboundary-throw-an-error-while-trying-to-get-the-image